# Cannot create client to azure storage account from jupyter stack container in spark/scala

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter

I'm trying to get some files from an Azure Storage account having the saskey for it.
So far I have been able to get them using python on jupyter stacks "jupyter/spark-all-notebook" container.

I'm using the following %spark_init magic to load the required libraries on kernel startup. At the moment I have commented the fasterxml.jackson jars since I have found out that the image is preloading version 2.12.3 automatically.

```
    %%init_spark
launcher.packages = ["com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha",
                     #"com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4",
                     #"com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.4",
                     #"com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4",
                     "com.azure:azure-storage-common:12.12.0",
                     "com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.12.0"]
```

However, when trying to create a connection to the storage account:

```
import com.azure.storage._
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder
import com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper

try{

   val storageKeyValue = "<<provided_sas_key>>"


  val blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
      .endpoint("https://<<account_name>>.blob.core.windows.net/" + "?" + storageKeyValue)
      .buildClient()
  }
  catch {
    case ex : Exception => {
      println ("\n" + ex)
      println ("\n" + ex.printStackTrace + "\n")
    }
    case ex : NoClassDefFoundError => {
        println (ex)
        println(ex.printStackTrace)
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error for undefined function:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableCoercionConfig com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()'
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:175)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:144)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:126)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.builder(XmlMapper.java:209)
  at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:137)
  at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:49)
  at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371)
  at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:132)
  at liftedTree1$1(<console>:44)
  ... 37 elided
```

I have tried changing the version for jackson core, dataformat and databind, but I think the notebook is loading 2.12.3 by default.

Am I missing a dependency or something?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing "javax.xml.stream" dependency. Here you can find the Jar but i don't know  how you can add it to python.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/1.0-2